# How to install Linux server via CentOS 7

Tags: linux, centos, 64bit, 32bit

I am fairly new to Linux, and trying to install my first Linux server via CentOS 7. 
I have an old Gateway desktop, with 32-bit (I think with either Windows 7, or 10).  And I noticed that now all the ISOs are 64-bit.

Does this mean I can't utilize this old machine, and convert it to a server to play around with it?

If so, how can I make it work?

Comment: Just get a LiveCD and try it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the "altarch" builds. In recent RHEL/CentOS releases, i386 is no longer a first class citizen.

Here's a link to a mirror with i386 ISO images -> http://mirror.centos.org/altarch/7/isos/i386/